# Ruby on Rails -> # rubocop:disable Metrics/BlockLength

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

Started in a new rails project and i'm seeing this line at the top of a class and not 100% certain on its function. I've done some small research but am unable to the definition of its actions.
Anyone able to help explain this to me?

> #rubocop:disable Metrics/BlockLength

Answer (score 0):

Class: RuboCop::Cop::Metrics::BlockLength

> This cop checks if the length of a block exceeds some maximum value.
> Comment lines can optionally be ignored. The maximum allowed length is
> configurable. The cop can be configured to ignore blocks passed to
> certain methods.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Metrics/BlockLength